# Need to create automatically new tab in google sheet when month is satrt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my challenge, Whenever new month is started, a new tab should be open an automatically in google spreadsheet based on the system date time.

Try to write script but not able to do.

Comment: When you say a new tab should be open do you mean creating a new sheet within the Spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes , you are correct, the new tab should be open within the spreadsheet.

Comment: Perfect, then the answer I provided should work exactly how you need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function newTab(){
  var dateObj = new Date();
  var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
  var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
  var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
  var name = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  ss.insertSheet(name);
  ss.getSheetByName(name).appendRow(["Name" , "Date", "Service"]);
}
```

This code will create a new sheet (tab) with the current date (yyyy/mm/dd format). To make it run once a month, you have to use installable triggers, [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) offers you instructions on how to do it. You would have to set the trigger to be time-driven, monthly and on the first day of the month.

Comment: Hi AMolina,  Thank you so much, its working fine, I have 50 google spread sheet should i open each sheet and save this code and setup trigger or is there any option for use this code for all sheet in a singe click, Im on searching my way. Please help me to do.

Comment: You could do that, but you'd need to do it for every new one as well. Another way would be to have a list of the Spreadsheet IDs, and loop through them using the method I provided, changing from `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` to `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` it would just be a matter of passing the ids from the Spreadsheets you want to edit and then you could create just one trigger.

Comment: Thank you so much , I will try and let you know.

Comment: Hi AMolina, I have used this code for multiple sheet and this code work perfectly, I want add header row with name like Name , Date, Service,etc, as default for everyone sheet, I tried as Freeze method but its not working. Please help if any code is there for add header as default value.

Comment: Updated my code, should add the header like you asked, you can add more elements to it depending what you want. If your problem was solved please consider marking the answer as accepted so the question is marked as solved.

Comment: Thanks.will try and let you know and one more thing for header need to add background color as green. Please help me.

Comment: After you have created the header use `ss.getRange(range).setBackground("#00FF00");` where `range` is the range of your header. [Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)

Comment: Hi AMolina, Thanks for the support, I want display month as character for first three letter like JAN so i tired this code but i could not get. please help me.var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
  var mname = month.setNumberFormat("MMM");

Comment: Sorry @VishwanathRengaraj but you should ask a new question, you can't just keep asking for new features after your original question was resolved. If my answer solved your original problem, please mark it as accepted and then post a new question if you have further problems

Comment: Hi AMolina, Thank you so much for your support, My challenge was completed just few minutes ago. This is my own idea and it was accomplished. I am new for code developer.

Comment: That's alright, and it's good that you resort to Stack for help, just try to avoid making several requests in the comments of an answer, and make separate questions to avoid making it confusing for people who might have similar challenges